# On arrival in Japan under the current COVID conditions, how does one go from the arrival gate to one's vehicle?

Tags: japan, covid-19

Assuming a person has arranged for a vehicle to take the person from the airport to the person's place of quarantine (home, hotel, elsewhere), how does the person get to the vehicle?

For example, say a person returning to Japan has a car parked in the parking ramp (which the person parked before leaving the country).  To allow the person to simply walk to the parking ramp would risk contact with others and seem to defeat the purpose of the quarantine requirement.

Similarly, if the person has arranged to meet a hired car or a driving family member, one would assume that the person wouldn't just be allowed to walk out to the general area where the car will be and wait unattended for the car to arrive.

How does a person go to the vehicle from the arrival gate?

Comment: I don't think the quarantine rules are meant to eliminate all contact, but rather to minimize contact, particularly prolonged contact. So I think your assumption is faulty and one would simply exit the terminal in the usual fashion. Likewise you are allowed to briefly leave your quarantine location to acquire necessities such as food.

Comment: Are you speaking from experience?  The govenment documents I have read do not allow for leaving the quarantine location.  If you have sources for your guesses, posting them as an answer would be very helpful.

Comment: What do the rules in the government documents you refer to in your question explicitly state on this topic? For example, the rules for my country talk about going straight to the place you’re staying to quarantine and only using public transport if you have no other option

Comment: Sorry, I elided that because I imagined someone who would be able to provide an answer would be someone already familiar with that background information.  I haven't been able to find government documents that state explicitly the answer to the question, hence the question, but I'll compile the specific related sources and information that I do have and add to the OP.

Comment: @Henris No direct experience, and don't remember sources, which is why I posted as a comment rather than an answer. I could well be wrong (though I wonder what the government expects a single person without a support network, particularly in a rural area, to do...) I did just now take a look at the Ministry of Foreign Affair's COVID page and also the agreement you have to sign on entry, and it doesn't say anything besides "no contact" - which strictly interpreted would preclude even non-public transportation other than driving yourself in your own car (as a rental would require contact...)

Comment: I agree with your points.  However https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/160832/concerning-covid-19-quarantine-on-return-to-japan-as-a-non-citizen-resident?rq=1 according to this answer, rental cars and hires are acceptable; government documents I have read (which I can't immediately source) have also stated the same, as well as that contact with people you live with during quarantine is acceptable.  There is a lot of seeming contradiction, and that's why I'd like to find a concrete official source with at least the answer to the OP.

Comment: Related to your last point, in addition to the OP I'd also like to find a source saying whether or not a family member picking you up is ok, but that's a separate question from this one...

Comment: @Henris What advice did the Japanese embassy where you reside provide when you contacted them?

Comment: I've not contacted any agency; that does seem like it would be helpful in addition to searching documents online.

Comment: Family member pickup answer, for anyone interested: https://www.mhlw.go.jp/stf/seisakunitsuite/bunya/0000121431_00098.html

Answer (score 4):

The answer that you do, indeed, **simply walk to your vehicle**.  The regulations prohibit using public transportation, but place no further requirements on private transportation.

More generally, Japan being an orderly society, COVID regulations are not enforced at gunpoint, you are simply expected to do the right thing.  You *are* required to sign a [Written Pledge](https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/000863646.pdf) on arrival at the airport where you promise to do so, and if you fail to do so and are caught, [consequences may include detention and, for foreign nationals, deportation](https://www.mofa.go.jp/ca/fna/page4e_001053.html):

> From January 14, 2021 until further notice, all Japanese nationals and
> foreign nationals with the status of residence are also required to
> pledge to refrain from using public transportation, and to be in
> quarantine at home or other designated areas, retain the location
> data, and provide it to the health centers or other institutions, if
> requested. (If separate quarantine measures are to be taken, those
> also need to be pledged.) They are required to sign and submit the
> Written Pledge when entering Japan. In case of
> violation, they may be subject to detention under Quarantine Act.